# Get items by hashtag from the Instagram API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am confused about Instagram API endpoints. Let us say I want to fetch all items from all available users by the specified hashtag and date-time of publishing, let us say it is `#animals` and all items published after 01-07-2017 01:00.

But according to the API description: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/, it looks like it allows to fetch data only for the authenticated user and only within his account (as it claims for the specific ACCESS_TOKEN which can not be obtained automatically). it is also claims for very weird MAX_TAG_ID and MIN_TAG_ID params (I have no idea how to fill them in my scenario).

**Question:** Am I right in my assumption, that it is not possible even on paid terms to register an app in the Instagram which will be allowed to search for items by the given hashtag (simply within all public content)?

Hint: for instance, this kind of requests are perfectly allowed in Google API and Twitter API.